# Sql XML query help no namespace

Tags: xml, attributes

I have a column in an sql table without a namespace.  I've selected two different rows to show you examples.  I need to select just the value for the ICD10CM_PREF named attribute.  Basically, I need to select and join based on another column in the table and then extract the value of the attribute name=ICD10CM_PREF.  How do I do this in a query?

this is close but I need to limit it to just the ICD10CM_PREF

```
SELECT cast(attr as xml).value('(/node())[1]', 'varchar(50)') from #myOQ where id=1
```

[image]

Comment: Found it - select convert(varchar(50),attr.query('/Attributes/Attribute[@name="ICD10CM_PREF"]/text()'))

Answer (score 0):

select convert(varchar(50),attr.query('/Attributes/Attribute[@name="ICD10CM_PREF"]/text()'))